# What is the formula for calculating "feature importance"?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a graph of the feature importance. What is the formula for calculating these values?

[image]

I got these values ​​after training and testing the model using

```
xgb.plot_importance (model)
```

I need a formula to describe mathematically how the calculation is done